# Reaching Elements inside of Shadow DOM

Tags: web-scraping, jira, jira-rest-api, shadow-dom

I am trying to simulate a user input by replicating their commenting action within the Jira/Atlassian environment.

The problem is that the text area I am looking to update is located within a shadow DOM.

I am unsure what to use instead of: ***document***.getElementById.... to target the correct DOM.

Thanks !!

Comment: is it marked as open? shadowRoot mode? if so, have you tried chaining method onto that base?

Comment: Hi @QHarr thanks for replying. I am unsure what the mode is. how can I check this ?

Comment: by inspecting the html

Comment: When I inspect the element it shows as "#document" should I be looking for something specific here ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode

Comment: So I looked at this and tried used "shadowRoot.mode;" in the console within the iframe that contains the Shadow DOM and it returns "undefined". this means it is closed then, correct ?

Comment: See chaining into shadowroot if open https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af?gi=9323da272bf0

Comment: Thanks for your help @QHarr ! As the Shadow DOM seems to be closed I will try and work with the Closed Mode part of the article you provided.